# Objects from Listview won't display when using for loop on template - Django

Tags: python, django, listview, django-class-based-views

I am trying to display all of the objects from Company, in a Listview by using a for-loop on the template(landingpage.html) but it comes out empty. The tricky part for me is that the Model class (Company) comes from a different directory than where the listview is created. I am importing the Model class (Company) in views.py but it still shows up empty on the template.

[image]

Any ideas on why this might be?

---

event/views.py

```
from company.models import Company

class LandingpageView(ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = "event/landingpage.html"
    ordering = ['date']
    context_object_name = 'event_list'

class LatestCompanyView(ListView):
    model = Company
    template_name = "event/landingpage.html"
```

---

event/urls.py

```
from .views import LatestCompanyView

urlpatterns = [
    path('event/landingpage/', LatestCompanyView.as_view(), name='landingpage'),
]
```

---

event/landingpage.html

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="row about-django">
    <div class="col-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <img class="about-django-img" src="{% static 'img/hero.png' %}">
    </div>
</div>
<h1>Events</h1>
<div class="event-container">
{% for Event in event_list %}
    <div class="row event-row">
        <div class="col-4 event-col"><img src="{{ Event.eventImage.url}}" alt="{{ Event.eventTitle }}"></div>
        <div class="col-4 event-col">
            <h3 class="event-title">{{ Event.eventTitle }}</h3>
            <div>Date: {{ Event.date }}</div>
            <div>Location: {{ Event.location }}</div>
            <div>Description: {{ Event.description }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 event-col"><a href="{{ Event.eventUrl }}" class="btn btn-event">Buy Tickets</a></div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
    </div>
        <h1>Latest</h1>
        <div class="event-container"> 
        {% for Company in company_list %}
            <h3 class="event-title">{{ Company.description }}</h3>
        {% empty %}
        Nothing here!
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

---

company/models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default = None)
description = models.TextField()


def __str__(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self.user, self.description)
```

Comment: Does substituting `company_list` by `object_list` works ?

Comment: Does that `Nothing is here!` show up in the page? Can you show more of your template, perhaps this loop is inside some if-else condtion / loop?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I've updated the template file

Comment: your updated template and the given view doesn't fit together. Where did event_list came from?

Comment: Abdul Aziz Barkat asked a good question about whether "Nothing is here!" is printed or not?

Comment: @normic Event is a Model class in event/model.py

Comment: @Guillaume Yes the page shows "Nothing is here!"

Comment: @NicolajSpiegelhauer that can mean there are no `Company` instances saved in the database, are you sure that there are `Company` instances saved in the database?

Comment: @NicolajSpiegelhauer: yes that's clear. But if your showing of LatestCompanyView is complete, it will only contain object_list (from Company model) and no event data at all. Or did you change get_context_data and didn't show it?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes, I have 14 registered Companies that I can see in the Django Admin control tower.

Comment: @normic LatestCompanyView is not suppose to contain any Event data. And I do not have a get_object_data method?

Comment: @normic See this line `return '%s_list' % object_list.model._meta.model_name` in the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b1a4b1f0bdf05adbd3dc4dde14228e68da54c1a3/django/views/generic/list.py#L104-L111), this means there should be a variable `company_list` in the context (don't know where OP expects `event_list` to come from though)

Comment: Could it have anything to do with using 2 for-loops on the same template? Because when I change the "company_list" to "object_list" I get the description from the Events I have created but not the Companies? 
I think the 2 for-loops doesn't register that there are 2 forms of data on the same template.

Comment: @NicolajSpiegelhauer No, you can even nest them. What does show up if you add a {{ company_list }} above the company loop? It _should_ give you contents of the queryset matched

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: You are totally right, I'm even using that ;) My answer was a reflex from (very) old Django days...

Comment: @normic nothing shows up when I add the {{ company_list }} above the company loop...

Comment: @NicolajSpiegelhauer: Cause there is no queryset. I just saw that you updated your posted view. Can you please clean up this a little. What is the current not working data? Your Company and Landingview are referring to the same template!? If you are really calling the LatestCompanyView, then the company_list  should be filled automatically

Answer (score 0):

event/views.py:

```
class LatestCompanyView(ListView):
    model = Company
    template_name = "event/landingpage.html"
    context_object_name = 'company_list'
```

Comment: as @AbdulAziz correctly pointed out in the above comments. This is not needed anymore in newer Django versions.